Selecting DataGridView on a Tab Page
I have a function to add a Tab Page to a Tab Control and then add a DataGridView to it.
    public void dgv_AddGrid(string dgvName)
    {
        int tabCount = tabControl1.TabCount;
        listBox1.Items.Add(tabCount.ToString());
        Application.DoEvents();
        tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, dgvName);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[0];
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name = dgvName;
        DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
        tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(grid);
        grid.ColumnCount = 3;
        grid.Width = tabControl1.Width;
        grid.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
        dgv = grid;     // This sets a Global variable to the newly created DataGridView
    }

I now need a way, after creating several Tab.DataGridView pairs to access a specific pair using the dgvName.
This is what I tried
    public void dgv_SelectTab_Grid_By_Name(string tabName)
    {
        if (tabControl1.TabPages[tabName] == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The requested Tab/Data Grid Combination does not exist.\r\nSelected Tab/Data Grid Combo is UNCHANGED!",
                            "Missing Tab", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[tabName];
            dgv = tabControl1.SelectedTab.grid;
        }
    }

I can't seem to find how to access the DataGridView grid on the selected tab page.
There is a global container: DataGridView dgv;
I am using ,NET Framework 4.6.2 to maintain compatibility with Win 10 without having to install other .NET

Used a Dictionary globally
Dictionary<string, DataGridView> dataGrids = new Dictionary<string, DataGridView>();

instead of:
DataGridView dgv;

in dgv_AddGrid
used
dataGrids.Add(dgvName, grid);

instead of
dgv = grid;

And to select the name Tab/Grid pair
dgv = dataGrids[tabName];

Note: my DataGridView code is set up so all related functions act on dgv.
